# android - phonegap file uploader plugin with progress bar in status bar

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Anyone know a phonegap file uploader plugin with progress bar in status bar. I found one here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader but no progress bar and maybe it outdated (2 years ago). Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know that's the only one.
I just tried it and it doesn't work very well.

The file gets uploaded but for some reason you first get a quickly increasing progress indication. Once that reaches 100% the file is actually starting to get uploaded and you still need to wait a lot of time without any indication of progress.

Comment: I've actually managaed to fix the plugin :) Once I've finished tweaking it I'll fork it on github and send the author a pull request.

Comment: Hi i wnat to upload a pdf file to server and i am searching for a file upload example from many days and i found fileUploader plugin in github but i am not able to implement it. Can u please show the full example if u r able to run the code.Thank you

Comment: How you solve the outdated issue? please help me. Am working in android, and the fileuploader.java file showing some error.

Answer (score 0):

it may be too late for the answer, but with the plugin file attached to the plugin dialogs you will be able to display the native progress.
The code example follows.

Cheers

```
function onSuccess(r) {
    navigator.notification.progressStop();
    console.log('success');
}

function onError(error) {
    navigator.notification.progressStop();      
}

var upload = function (imageURI) {
  navigator.notification.progressStart('', 'Uploading image...');
  var fileURL = imageURI;
  var uri = encodeURI(server + "uploadPacientes.php");
  var codigo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 655365456342524252);
  var paciente = document.getElementById('paciente_nome');
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey = "file";
  options.fileName = paciente + codigo + ".jpg"; 
  options.mimeType = "image/jpg";
  var headers = {
    'headerParam': 'headerValue'
  }
  options.headers = headers;
  var ft = new FileTransfer();

  ft.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percentual = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 
  100);
        navigator.notification.progressValue(percentual);

    } else {
        navigator.notification.progressValue('0');
    }
  }
  ft.upload(fileURL, uri, onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reply late, but I hope it helps someone in the future! Cheers

```
 function salvarARQUIVOS(superFILE) {
    var tipoArquivo = $( "input[name=tipoArquivo]:checked" ).val();
    var dataArquivo = $('#dataArquivo').val();
    var arquivoFile = superFILE;
    $('#btnARQUIVO').html('ENVIANDO');

if (dataArquivo === "") {
    $('#btnARQUIVO').html('SALVAR');
    aviso('Informe a data do arquivo');
    return true;
}

var extensao = arquivoFile.substr(arquivoFile.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
if (extensao != "pdf") {
    aviso('Somente arquivos em pdf');
    return true;
}
myApp.showIndicator();
var arq = arquivoFile.substr(arquivoFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
arq = arq.replace(/[\W_]/g, "-");
var uri = encodeURI(serv + "uploadPDF.php");
var nome_arquivo = arq.replace('-pdf', '.pdf');
console.log('nome_arquivo = > ' + nome_arquivo);
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = nome_arquivo;
options.mimeType = "application/pdf";
options.chunkedMode = false;
var headers = {
    'headerParam': 'headerValue'
};
     options.headers = headers;
     var ft = new FileTransfer();
     ft.upload(arquivoFile, uri, onSuccessoArquivo, onErrorArquivo, options);

     function onSuccessoArquivo(r) {
         myApp.hideIndicator();
         linkArquivo = 'arquivosExames/' + nome_arquivo;
         idPaciente = $('#idPaciente').val();
         String = 'idPaciente=' + idPaciente + '&tipoArquivo=' + tipoArquivo + '&dataArquivo=' + dataArquivo + '&linkArquivo=' + linkArquivo;
         console.log(String);
         $.ajax({
           url: serv + "saveServ.php",
           type: "GET",
           data: String,
           dataType: "json",
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) {
              $('#btnARQUIVO').html('SALVAR');
              myApp.hideIndicator();
              changePage('pagelistaarquivos');
              aviso('Enviado');
           }
        });
    }

    function onErrorArquivo(error) {
       myApp.hideIndicator();
       $('#btnARQUIVO').html('SALVAR');
       aviso('Erro ao enviar o arquivo ' + error.code);
    }
}
```